# add CSS in to a specific post by classic WordPress post editor without any plugin

Tags: css, wordpress

how to apply unique CSS styling to an individual page of content without using any plugin such as TinyMCE in WordPress classic editor

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it as inline css like defining inline

or

can you as external css by adding the css in style.css with unique class or id defined in your html

refer: https://torquemag.io/2016/09/add-custom-styles-wordpress-editor-manually-via-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

The `body` tag stores unique class for each posts. so you can target css for each posts as

body.post-1 { ... }

body.post-2 { ... }